# Grails + Selenium + EasyB +spring-security-core: ifAnyGranted Isn't Working

Tags: grails, spring-security, selenium-rc, easyb

Grails 1.3.5 and have selenium-rc, easyb, and spring-security-core plugins installed.  Everything seems to work really well except this one case I've run into.  I have a page I am testing which has the following markup:

```
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles='ROLE_ADMIN'>
    <span class="menuButton">
      <g:link mapping="adminPage">
        <g:message code="default.admin.label" default="--Admin--"/>
      </g:link>
    </span>
</sec:ifAnyGranted>
```

When running the application normally, everything works fine.  If I'm logged in as a regular user, the Admin link doesn't show.  If I log in as an admin, the link does show up.  When running my test, no matter who is logged in, the check fails, so the Admin link is never rendered.

```
scenario "An Admin User logs into the system", {
   when "the user completes the login form with proper credentials", {

   grailsApplication = ApplicationHolder.application
   springSecurityService = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.getBean("springSecurityService")

   def userAdmin = new User(username: 'testAdmin', firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Admin', enabled: true, password: springSecurityService.encodePassword("password")).save(flush: true)
   def roleAdmin = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
   UserRole.create(userAdmin, roleAdmin)

   selenium.openAndWait("/platform/login/auth")
   selenium.type('j_username', 'testAdmin')
   selenium.type('j_password', 'password')
   selenium.clickAndWait('signInBtn')

 }
 then "the user should be logged in and viewing their My Account page, as an admin", {
   selenium.isTextPresent("Welcome Test").shouldBe true
   selenium.isElementPresent('link=Admin').shouldBe true

 }
}
```

Other tags work just fine such as ifLoggedIn and ifNotLoggedIn.  Anyone know if this is a known issue or any other info on it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the flush

```
 UserRole.create(userAdmin, roleAdmin, true)
```

http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/4%20Required%20and%20Optional%20Domain%20Classes.html#4.2%20Authority%20Class